# Edge length of a Dodecahedron

Tags: geometry

Good morning,

If I have a $12$ sided regular pentagonal structure - that is, a Dodecahedron - and the widest point is $3.5m$ in diameter, what is the length of an edge (if they are all the same).

Regards,

Connor

Comment: Please refer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodecahedron.

Comment: http://www.kjmaclean.com/Geometry/dodecahedron.html

Comment: I have reviewed this page as well as yours and am still struggling to find an answer to my question.

Comment: I may be wrong but it seems you have the diameter of the dodecahedron and you want the length of the pentagon. It seems to me that if you construct a circumscribed sphere, due to symmetry(ref your link), the diameter of the dodecahedron (either CT or DP) = diameter of the sphere.

Comment: Amazing, thankyou!

Answer (score 2):

The radius $R$ of the spherical surface passing through all 20 identical vertices of a dodecahedron with edges length $a$ is given by generalized formula (derived in [HCR's Formula for platonic solids](https://www.academia.edu/9727820/HCRs_Formula_for_Regular_n-Polyhedron_Mathematical_analysis_of_regular_n-polyhedrons_all_five_platonic_solids_))$$\bbox[4pt, border: 1px solid blue;]{R=\frac{\sqrt{3}(\sqrt{5}+1)a}{4}} $$ $$\implies a=\frac{4R}{\sqrt{3}(\sqrt{5}+1)}$$$$\implies \color{purple}{a=\frac{R(\sqrt{5}-1)}{\sqrt{3}}}$$ Since $R=\frac{3.5}{2}$ hence the edge length of dodecahedron is $$a=\frac{(3.5)(\sqrt{5}-1)}{2\sqrt{3}}$$$$=\frac{R(\sqrt{5}-1)}{\sqrt{3}}\approx 1.248877314 \space m$$

Answer (score 1):

All Platonic solids except the tetrahedron are centrally symmetric, meaning they are preserved under reflection through the origin. (ref: wiki [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_solid#Symmetry_groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic%5fsolid#Symmetry%5fgroups)). So diameter of a dodecahedron = diameter of the circumscribed sphere.

Radius of circumscribed sphere and the side of a pentagon in dodecfahedron are related by $R \approx 1.4 a$. (ref. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodecahedron).

So $a \approx \frac{R}{1.4} = \frac{D}{2.8} = 1.25m$